# How do I get command line args when using `spring-boot:run`

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scala

I have the following Scala code...

```
object TestCompany extends App {
  SpringApplication run classOf[TestCompanyApp]
}
@SpringBootApplication
class TestCompanyApp extends CommandLineRunner{
  override def run(args: String*): Unit = {
    println(args.mkString("|"))
  }
}
```

I try running like `mvn clean install spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=argOne,argTw` but args is still empty. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to convert the Array to varargs like this...

```
object TestCompany {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    SpringApplication.run(classOf[TestCompanyApp], args:_*)
  }
}
```

Now this works...

`mvn clean install spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=test`